# How to get the position of object in Three.js relative to the camera to draw a trail?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have an object (a pen) in my scene, which is rotating around its axis in the render loop.

```
    groupPen.rotation.y += speed;
    groupPen.rotation.x += speed;
```

and I have also a TrackballControls, which allows the user to rotate the whole scene.

What I now want is to get the "real" position of the pen (or its pick) and place small spheres to create a trail behind it.

This means I need to know where the camera is looking at and place the trail spheres behind the peak of the pen and exclude them from the animation and the TrackballControls.

What I tried is:

```
groupSphereTrail.lookAt(camera.position);
```

didn't work. Means no reaction at all.

```
camera.add(groupSphereTrail);
```

didn't work. groupSphereTrail is than not in the view area, couldn't make it visible - manipulating position.z didn't help.

Then I tried something like sending a tray with traycaster. The idea was to send a ray from the center of the camera through the peak of the pen and then draw the trail there. But then I still doesn't have the "real" position.

Another idea was to create a 2d vector of the current position of the pen peak and just draw an html element on top of the canvas:

```
    var p = penPeak.position.clone();
    var vector = p.project(camera);
    vector.x = (vector.x + 1) / 2 * width;
    vector.y = -(vector.y - 1) / 2 * height;
```

but this also doesn't work.

What could be another working solution?

Current progress:
https://zhaw.swissmade.xyz
(click on the cap of the pen to see the writing - this writing trail should stay at its place when you rotate the camera)

Comment: Why not simply draw your spheres at the peak of the pen?

Comment: @TheJim01 because they would rotate/animate with the peak when you rotate the camera. I want them to stick on the screen after they were drawn at the same position of the peak of the pen.

Comment: Do you _need_ the result to be 3D? Because you could overlay a second transparent canvas over the three.js canvas, and draw to it using a 2D context by unprotecting the pen tip's position (XYZ) into screen space (XY).

Comment: I think 2D would be a nice start. Or even a solution when the 2D Canvas is behind the transparent 3D Scene.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood the question right, you want to show the trail as if it were draw on the screen itself (screen space)?

```
yourTrailParticle.position.project(camera)
camera.add(yourTrailParticle)
```

That's the basic idea, but it gets a bit tricky with `PerspectiveCamera`. You could set up a whole new `THREE.Scene` to hold the trail, and render it with a fixed size orthographic camera.

The point is `.project()` will give you a normalized screen space coordinate of a world space vector, and you need to keep it somehow in sync with that camera (since the screen is too). The perspective camera has distortion so you need to figure out the appropriate distance to map the coordinate to. With a separate scene, this may become easier.